# Stripes does not see my ActionBean

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, stripes

I'm having again some little problems with Stripes, this time with the link tag
Basically i am calling an action bean from a jsp like so:

```
<s:link beanclass="users.action.UserFormActionBean">...</s:link>
```

The exception i receive is:

```
The value supplied for the 'beanclass' attribute does not represent a valid ActionBean.
```

Which is not true because that class implements ActionBean (via a class helper called BaseActionBean) and it contains a @DefaultHandler.

I really cant figure out why it does not work, below i will post the two classes

```
public class UserFormActionBean extends BaseActionBean{

private User user;

private static final String FORM="/WEB-INF/jsp/form.jsp";

private static final String LIST="/WEB-INF/jsp/list.jsp";

@DefaultHandler
public Resolution goToForm(){

    return new ForwardResolution(FORM);
}

/**
 * A getter for the user
 * @return
 */
public User getUser(){

    return this.user;
}

/**
 *save the new user into db 
 */
public Resolution save(User user){

    DaoUtil.save(user);

    return new ForwardResolution(LIST);
}
```

}

the helper:

```
public class BaseActionBean implements ActionBean{

private ActionBeanContext ctx;

public void setContext(ActionBeanContext ctx){

    this.ctx=ctx;
}

public ActionBeanContext getContext(){

    return this.ctx;
}
```

}

Comment: It is solved sorry i had a problem in the classpath!

Answer (score 0):

Check your package declaration for UserFormActionBean it should be:

```
package users.action;
```

(Although I would recommend using another package name as this name does not conform to the general [Java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) that describes that a package name should start with one of the top-level domain names of your organization).